# Finding constant for orthonormality

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, orthonormal, constants

Assume the problem

\begin{align}
f''(x) &= \lambda f(x) \\
f'(0) &= f(1) = 0 \\
\end{align}

with solution:

$$
\phi_n(x) = c \cdot\cos\left( \frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}x\right), \quad n = 1,2,\dots
$$

Now, if we want the solution to satisfy $\|f\|_2 = 1$, then:

$$
|c|\left(\int_0^1 \cos^2\left( \frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}x\right)  \right)^{\frac12} =1 \iff c = \pm \sqrt{2}
$$

But I don't think $c = -\sqrt{2}$ $\,$ is an acceptable value if we want $\phi_n(x)$ to be the orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,1)$. Any suggestions why we reject the negative value?

Comment: Why do you think $-\sqrt{2}$ is not acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with taking $c=-\sqrt{2}$.  Indeed, if you take an orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ and replace some of the $e_n$'s with their negatives, they remain an orthonormal basis (it does not change $\langle e_n,e_m\rangle$ for $m\neq n$ since $(-1)\cdot 0=0$, and it does not change $\langle e_n,e_n\rangle$ since you get two factors of $-1$ which cancel out).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused. The constant $c$ could have all the values you want, but the functions belonging to $L^2(0,1)$ are functions in which the $x$ are in $(0,1)$ it is not the same.

Edit: In you could also have more than one ortonormal basis for a $L^p$ space. A nice exercise for you would be to see if both constant define the same orthomoral system due to the $cos$ properties.

Comment: So:
$$
\phi_n(x) = -\sqrt{2} \cdot\cos\left( \frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}x\right), \quad n = 1,2,\dots
$$
satisfy all the conditions of the problem?

Comment: For having orthonormal basis your set of functions should satisfy that $<\phi_n,\phi_m>_{L^2 (0,1)}=0$ iff $n\neq m$. And also the property of having $L^2$ norm equal to $1$. I do not see why the orthonormal basis of the space depends on your ODE. For having a basis of the space you should have $e_n(x)=e^{2\pi inx}$ for all natural numbers.

Comment: @energy The ODE is relevant here because there is a theorem which states that any eigenvalue problem with symmetric boundary conditions has eigenfunction solutions which are orthogonal for distinct eigenvalues. This lets you omit the proof of orthogonality, and simply choose a constant for which orthonormality applies.